# Strange IIS/ASP.NET JIT Compilation Issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've got extremely strange behavior on one of my pages. I was able to get a work-around in place, but I'd like to get input on why this error is happening (and why my work-around actually works).

(Let me also say that this is in no way, shape, or form my code...so please don't bash me too hard)

When loading the page, we're getting

> BC30456 'InitializeCulture' is not a
>   member of...

I worked through the tips here and nothing worked:

[BC30456 Fixes](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/54a40a36-209a-46ee-b834-df946532719f)

I was able to get the page back up and working by changing

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" 
    CodeFile="newsproduct_rss.aspx.vb" Inherits="product_nrss" %>
```

to

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" 
    CodeFile="newsproduct_rss.aspx.vb" Inherits="product_nrss" Debug="true" %>
```

I'm hoping there's something obvious I'm missing so please, enlighten me!

**Also, if anybody needs more details...just let me know and I'll supply everything I can** (if you can't tell, this one is really eating at me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that my PowerShell-Fu missed a stupid error on the server.

There were two files declaring the same methods of the same partial class. Oddly enough there were two pages, each references a different copy of the partial class.

Got rid of one of the copies and voila! no more `Debug="true"` needed.

Still leaves me a little curious as to why adding `Debug="true"` allowed the page to execute at all...

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could add a Title="Something" to the page. I know the asp.net compiler is flakey at best. I've had published sites where two pages will not work, just for it to be a missing title or something.

Answer (score 0):

The debug statement really should be in the web.config of the application. My first suggestion was going to be to make sure that the ASP.Net version you're using is installed correctly. I did find this article (which I'm sure you read already) that details some of the work-arounds to this problem.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/54a40a36-209a-46ee-b834-df946532719f

Comment: The web.config of the app already has Debug="false" set there. I added Debug="true" to the page itself because I was going to see if I could get any more information about the problem...and voila, it just started working.

...and I have the same link in my original question. Thanks though.

Comment: Yah, saw that after I posted it, decided to leave it since it had the url out and about. You might try the IIS Debug Diagnostic tools. This looks more like an IIS problem than a code problem.